# How to customize the global search to hide Opportunity records with certain stage

Tags: opportunity, global-search

I would like to know how to customize the global search in way that none of my users can see Opportunity records with certain stage.

I have created a new stage called "Test Stage" in the Opportunity stage picklist.

What I would like to achieve is to customize the global search to NOT show Opportutnity records with stage equal to "Test Stage".

Please advise how this can be achieved in Salesforce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. If you can see the record, it will appear in the search results. The only way you could achieve this is to configure sharing settings so they can no longer see the records.